# AngularJS2 : Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm starting an AngularJS2 web-app, and I've started with a login component.
I have a text input linked to a controller variable, which is also displayed in the view. However, for some reason, updating the text filed does not update the text display next to it.
However, alert()-ing my edited variables does display the changes made.
Here is my code :

**login.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule }              from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

    login: string = "test1";
    pass:  string = "test2";

    onSubmit(): void {
        alert("Form submit: " + this.login + this.pass);
    }
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div id="login">

    {{this.login}}
    {{this.pass}}

    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <label for="form-login">Login</label>
        <input type="text"     class="form-input" id="form-login" name="form-login" [(ngModel)]="login"><br>

        <label for="form-pass">Mot de passe</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-input" id="form-pass"  name="form-pass"  [(ngModel)]="pass">

        <button type="submit" id="button-connexion" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Connexion</button>

    </form>

</div>
```

And my header of **index.html** for importing scripts :

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

My console displays this error :

```
core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost/app/login/login.component.html:13:46 caused by: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_LoginComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/LoginComponent/component.ngfactory.js:177:42)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9355:18)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9448:48)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_LoginComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/LoginComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9355:18)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9448:48)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7338:24)
at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3747:46)
at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3224:20)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3198:26)
```

Comment: In your `login.component.html` you have `<button type="submit" id="button-connexion" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Connexion</button>`, but in your `login.component.ts` there is no variable `heroForm`. That is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it, this was a dumb copy/paste from the AngularJS exampe ! It's funny how Angular blocks everything when you have an error !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I realized when I have used an undefined variable on my html page it caused the error.
Basically, Either you need to define the variable or delete from your html page.

As I saw you haven't defined `heroForm` in your component.